# Select content based on logged-in user ID and drop-down selected users

Tags: 8, views

I try to make a relation between two reference fields inside one node. For example, this node (type: groups) I've created:

Example (node) 1:

> **Group 1** has two users and one course
>
> -- Reference field: Users
> --- User 1
> --- User 2
>
> -- Reference field: Courses
> --- Information technology

Example (node) 2:

> **Group 2** has one user and one course
>
> -- Reference field: Users
> --- User 2
>
> -- Reference field: Courses
> --- Psychology

Currently I'm using views for it. My goal is, if a user is logged in, all courses are showing up which is associated with his group.

Group 1: User 1 and User 2 should both see the course: Information Technology.
Group 2: User 2 should also see: Psychology.

I'm not sure if this is possible with views and if my current structure is right?

Comment: You will probably need a views contextual filter https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/add-a-contextual-filter-to-a-view and perhaps a relationship https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/add-a-relationship-to-a-view.  Here is a simple contextual filter to understand to get you started https://wishdesk.com/blog/drupal-8-views-contextual-filters.  This module https://www.drupal.org/project/user_field_value might also be helpful.  Please try to setup your view and contextual filters and update the post with the details.

Comment: Here is another similar contextual filter question you might want to try to understand https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277569/how-can-i-display-a-list-of-users-who-have-the-same-taxonomy-term/277607#277607

Comment: Yes it can be done with Views, as can many other structure combinations. I'd start with a list of Courses, add the Reverse Relationship for the group (Courses field), add another Relationship, for the Users (referenced from the group), make it use the first Relationship, require both. Then add a Contextual filter for the user ID that uses the second Relationship and set a default value from the logged in user context. You can find similar answers that do something similar where you can learn what the steps mean.

Comment: Thank you guys, I figured it out the way you told me @prkos.

Comment: You can add your answer to help others with the same problem ;)